# LBYouTubeView: How to use Storyboard object instead of CGRectMake

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, youtube-api

I'm using the LBTyouTubeView script at https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView which creates it's own view to embed the video.

Code in Sample:

```
self.controller.delegate = self;
self.controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
self.controller.view.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:self.controller.view];
```

I want to attach the controller to an object in the storyboard instead of using CGRectMake.  Would I use a View object in storboard?

And how would I modify this code to use that Storyboard object rather than creating one from code?  I've been searching around and haven't found any information.